# MySQL 5.7.25 [innoDB], index cardinality suddenly reset/change back to 1

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am using MySql v 5.7.25 with innoDB.

I have a table `inventories` with 100 mio data

this is what it looks like when `SHOW CREATE TABLE inventories;`

note: removed unrelated field.

```
CREATE TABLE `inventories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` decimal(50,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `line_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_inventories_on_line_number` (`line_number`),
  KEY `idx_pr_ln` (`product_id`,`line_number`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39905 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

the problem is index cardinality on index `idx_pr_ln` suddenly reset to 1 on field line_number.

```
mysql > show index from inventories;

| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name                              | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
|-------------|------------|---------------------------------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|------|------------|---------|---------------|
| inventories |          1 | index_inventories_on_line_number      |            1 | line_number | A         |     3025563 |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| inventories |          1 | idx_pr_ln                             |            1 | product_id  | A         |     4337902 |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| inventories |          1 | idx_pr_ln                             |            2 | line_number | A         |           1 |          |        | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
```

every `SELECT` query that use index `idx_pr_ln` now do FULL table scan because of cardinality 1 on line_number.

after I do `ANALYZE TABLE inventories`, it will back to the 'correct' value around 100 mio.
but in a few day, it happened again (reset to 1 again).

**my question are**

why this cardinality suddenly reset/change to 1?

have any of you guys ever experience this?

is this a bug on MySql?

Any explanation / suggestion are appreciated.
Thanks.

NOTE: no changes on table or index,
no alter table, no add / remove index. 
only data that may changes (CUD)

EDIT: 
the select statement is like this

`SELECT product_id, line_number FROM inventories WHERE product_id = 123 AND line_number < 321`

Comment: Normally the SHOW INDEX FROM table_name would show in the Key_name column PRIMARY for the PRIMARY key listed in the CREATE TABLE specification - unless someone has ALTERed the table to 'REMOVE' the primary key.  Please POST current  TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE `inventories`; so we can see the current definition of the table.  What do you mean by 'removed unrelated field'?

Comment: Sorry if my explanation is confusing.
PRIMARY key is listed on the create table, 1 line before KEY `index_inventories_on_line_number` (`line_number`).
what I mean by removed unrelated fields is I didn't show it on the post since it not relate to my question. there is debit, credit, quantity, and more columns on the table.

I think, I found what cause the index cardinal to be 1. will edit the question soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem for my question, that cause index cardinality to be 1.

as @Rick James mentioned

> InnoDB will make a few random probes to determine statistics (cardinality) of columns. If it happens to see unique values for line_number, then the cardinality is set to 1. If not, some larger value is used.

and after reading this mysql doc
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html

this was cause by statistic update by mysql when there is 10% of the data (around 10 mio in this case) has changed.

> STATS_AUTO_RECALC specifies whether to automatically recalculate persistent statistics. The value DEFAULT causes the persistent statistics setting for the table to be determined by the innodb_stats_auto_recalc setting. A value of 1 causes statistics to be recalculated when 10% of table data has changed. A value 0 prevents automatic recalculation for the table. When using a value of 0, use ANALYZE TABLE to recalculate statistics after making substantial changes to the table.
>
> STATS_SAMPLE_PAGES specifies the number of index pages to sample when cardinality and other statistics are calculated for an indexed column, by an ANALYZE TABLE operation

with the default setting STATS_AUTO_RECALC=1 and STATS_SAMPLE_PAGES=20, there is a chance that mysql scan sample pages that contain a distinct value (only 1 distinct value on 20 pages sample).

after I update STATS_SAMPLE_PAGES=30, it less likely to have cardinal 1.

Answer (score 0):

The 1's in `SHOW INDEXES` are perfectly normal.  They do *not* indicate the current value.

"index_inventories_on_line_number" has one column, sequence number 1 of 1
"idx_pr_ln" has 2 columns, numbered 1 and 2.

The "cardinality" for the two columns of the second index are "4337902" for the first column, meaning that there are "a lot of different values".  For each of those, the second column is unique or close to unique (the "1").

In no way does MySQL/InnoDB manipulate the values of any of those columns other than the `PRIMARY KEY` column, which is `id`.  It will be incremented, except that `TRUNCATE TABLE` will reset it.

> every SELECT query that use index idx_pr_ln now do FULL table scan because of cardinality 1 on line_number.

That depends.

For `SELECT ... WHERE line_number = 432`, yes, it will do a full table scan.  This is because `line_number` is not *first* in the composite index.

For `SELECT ... WHERE product_id = 987`, it will use the index.

For further discussion, please provide sample `SELECTs`.

> cardinality on index idx_pr_ln suddenly reset to 1 on field line_number

InnoDB will make a few random probes to determine statistics (cardinality) of columns.  If it happens to see unique values for `line_number`, then the cardinality is set to 1.  If not, some larger value is used.

The statistics are used to decide on optimizing queries.  Let's see a query that is running slower than you think it should.  *That* is where we should focus.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. 

the SELECT is like this : 
`SELECT product_id, line_number FROM inventories where product_id = 123 and line_number < 321`. 

you are correct about this
> InnoDB will make a few random probes to determine statistics (cardinality) of columns. If it happens to see unique values for line_number, then the cardinality is set to 1. If not, some larger value is used.

I found the answer for my question. 
will edit it on the question or on this answer so I can mark it as answered.

this is because of the `innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages`